# how to download wso2 emm server version 2.0.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I tried to download  wso2 emm server version 2.0.1 but download link is not working and i went to previous releases and downloaded it.
Url : http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/

Comment: Do you still have the problem?

Comment: I just tried and it works. Did you get any errors or still face same issue?

Comment: I downloaded wso2emm-2.0.0, i cannot able to download verison 2.0.1

Comment: @Nikhil : Where is your location?

Comment: @ Abimaran Kugathasan : Can you tell me how to download wso2 emm server version 2.0.1?

Answer (score 1):

The [download link](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/#download) in WSO2 EMM page is working and i download WSO2 EMM 2.0.1 with out any problem.
Please visit http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/ and download WSO2 EMM 2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

The download link to download WSO2 EMM 2.0.1 is http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/ . If this doesn't work for you please contact your network administrator and check your fire wall settings.

Comment: I was able to download EMM 2.0.1 from http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/  without any issue